# configure nginx to route http to different upstreams

Tags: http, nginx

```
upstream A {
    server aa:8080;
}

upstream B {
    server bb:8080;
}

server {
    listen       aa:8080;

 location /aaa/ {
    proxy_pass http://A/;
 }

 location /bbb/ {
    proxy_pass http://B/;
 }

 location / {
     rewrite (/aaa/(.*))$ http://aa:8080$1 break;
     proxy_pass              http://bb/;

 }
```

On receving a request with url containing aaa I want the request to be routed to upstream A, and with bbb to B. location block with /aaa/ and /bbb/ do not work. In rewrite I can't use proxy_pass. 
if I add ($uri ~ "aaa"), then I notice logs
"aaa" matches "/aaa/aaa", client: 1.1.1.1, server: , request: "GET /aaa/aaa?wsdl HTTP/1.1", host: "1.2.3.4:8080"

How can I route requests to different upstreams based on URL content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use successfully location blocks which look like this:

```
upstream A {
    server aa:8080;
}

location ~ ^/aaa/ {
  proxy_pass http://A;
}
```

The differences are using a regex match and proxying via the upstream name (transformed into a psuedo-URL) rather than the real URL/port.

Comment: Facing another issue now. Specifying  listen ip:8080 works fine. However, this fails listen localhost:8080 ip:8080. What changes need to be done to intercept all request to :8080 regardless of request having the ip/localhost/loopback